# Как с помощью JS определить ip пользователя?

Tags: javascript

Хочу сделать так что бы JS определял Ip пользователя при запуске скрипта, но не знаю как это сделать. Подскажете?

Comment: только на сервере можно попробовать определить ip пользователя, однако можно послать запрос на сторонний сервис для этого

Comment: JS должен обратиться на какой нибудь сервер, например через ajax и сервер может сообщить ему с какого ip он получил запрос

Comment: И как это в коде написать?

Comment: @Ёжик тут код не  пишут за вас. Тут поправляют ваши ошибки. Наработки есть ? В гугле хоть искали.

Comment: Конечно искал, я бы суда не обратился бы если бы нашел.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Только на сервере можно попробовать определить публичный ip пользователя, однако можно послать запрос на сторонний сервис для этого

```js
fetch('https://ipapi.co/json/')
  .then(d => d.json())
  .then(d => document.querySelector('#ip').innerHTML = d.ip);
```

```html
<div id="ip"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Ёжик всегда пожалуйста

Comment: @StrangerintheQ благодаря WebRTC, очень легко получить локальный IP-адрес

Comment: @ДенисНебесный а толку от него? это в 50% случаев адрес машины в подсети не имеющей отношения к интернету

Comment: @ДенисНебесный 192.168.80.29

Comment: @StrangerintheQ хакерам удобно. Понятно какой ip (с большой долей вероятности) у роутера, что бы его ломать изнутри

Comment: @ДенисНебесный зря удалили, верните - плюсик поставлю, хоть это и багофича, кому-нибудь бы пригодилось, однако там не лучший варинат был, есть короче если поштудировать en.so

Answer (score 0):

```js
function findIP(onNewIP) {
  var myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
  var pc = new myPeerConnection({
      iceServers: []
    }),
    noop = function() {},
    localIPs = {},
    ipRegex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g,
    key;

  function ipIterate(ip) {
    if (!localIPs[ip]) onNewIP(ip);
    localIPs[ip] = true;
  }
  pc.createDataChannel("");
  pc.createOffer(function(sdp) {
    sdp.sdp.split('\n').forEach(function(line) {
      if (line.indexOf('candidate') < 0) return;
      line.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
    });
    pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
  }, noop);
  pc.onicecandidate = function(ice) {
    if (!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex)) return;
    ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
  };
}



var ul = document.createElement('ul');
ul.textContent = 'Ваш IP: '
document.body.appendChild(ul);

function addIP(ip) {
  console.log('Ваш IP: ', ip);
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = ip;
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

findIP(addIP);
```